# Typescript index access with strictNullChecks turned off

Tags: typescript

The following code works when `strictNullChecks` are enabled.

```js
interface IData {
  a: number;
  b: string;
}

const data: Partial<IData> = {};

// I am doing "as const" to make 'a' and 'b' string literal
// keys of IData. In the real code, these keys would come from elsewhere.
for (const key of ['a', 'b'] as const) {
  data[key] = undefined;
}

console.log(data);
```

When the flag is off, it gives error:

```
Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'.(2322)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strict=false&noImplicitAny=false&strictNullChecks=false&strictFunctionTypes=false&strictPropertyInitialization=false&strictBindCallApply=false&module=1&ts=4.6.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBE5jsg3gWAChlk4AuZEAVwFsAjaAbiJLooGcwpQBzZwgL5EiCAPYhOyACZZyyAApwoYYHAA2AHgyyAfMgC8eAfyIxRUZAAoxEsMgDWEAJ7JRMZAG0A5HC8AaZC86LwBdUnZkG04ASjwWaVkPRycwwyoQKQgYUAgpfiFCEXF2UTUIADo1UR5LGWxoxiA)

Why?

Is there some way to overcome this without enabling `strictNullChecks` or using `any`?

Comment: "without using `any`"?  You are already using `any` in your example and there's an error.  Are you saying you don't want an additional `any` somewhere?  What you're doing is already not type safe (assigning empty objects to `number` and `string` props) so I'm not quite understanding what you're going for here.  Could you fix the example code so that you're doing something reasonable?

Comment: The answer to "why" is because you are trying to assign a value of a property which cannot safely take a defined value; it would have to be both a `string` and a `number`, and no value satisfies that.  As for overcoming without enabling `--strictNullChecks` (which you really *should* do, but whatever), that strongly depends on the use case.  You can write `{} as never` and suppress the error, but I can't imagine why you'd want to assign `{}` to begin with.

Comment: Ignore the `{} as any` part, in the real code this assignment is different. I just pared it down for a workable example. It doesn't matter what I put there, the index access is still `never`. I guess `as never` is a workable alternative to doing `as any` on the `data`, but there's got to be something better...

Comment: I've edited the question to remove `as any`. It was admittedly confusing... :)

Comment: You've removed `any` but now your question now refers to an error that does not occur; could you please ensure you've got a [mre]?  The value `null` shouldn't be assigned there either, although with `--strictNullChecks` off I guess `null` and `undefined` look the same; perhaps `undefined` would be better in any case? Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w1ybKw).   That would give you behavior where there's no error with the flag on but an error with the flag off.  Feels like the best way of phrasing the question to me.

Comment: @jcalz you're right, I edited to `undefined`

Comment: Honestly it's hard to find canonical info about what happens when `--strictNullChecks` off, since it's almost universally recommended to turn it on.  I know that only `never` is considered assignable to `never`, and that without strict null checks, `null` and `undefined` get absorbed in unions, so the property types of `Partial<IData>` are just `number` and `string` (instead of `number | undefined` and `string | undefined`), and their intersection is `never`.  ...

Comment: ... so then it won't let you assign `undefined` to `never`, and you get an error.  Possibly without strict null checks, `undefined` and `null` should be considered assignable to `never`, but I don't know if this is a bug/limitation/intended.  One could imagine filing an issue in GitHub about it, but I don't know if that would help.  I think `undefined as never` is a completely reasonable workaround in the meantime though. ...

Comment: ... Is there some reason why `undefined as never` doesn't work for you?  You said "there's got to be something better" but I'm not sure how to interpret that.  There are situations where TS can't figure something out and type assertions are the way to deal with it because there isn't anything "better".  In the absence of anything "better", should I post an answer with this info?  Or leave and hope someone else finds what you're looking for?

Comment: @jcalz `as never` should work fine. Thanks for the explanation what is happening!

I personally never liked super-strict checking, but if this is becoming an edge case land, perhaps it's time to get on board :/

Comment: @jcalz please write it in an answer to assign you points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a limitation of TypeScript when [the `--strictNullChecks` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks) is off, but I have not found an existing issue in GitHub about it.  It is almost universally [recommended](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#strictnullchecks-off) to turn *on* `--strictNullChecks`, so there's not anywhere near as much coverage in GitHub and the documentation of how things behave when it's off.

My analysis here is that a few things are interacting poorly:

- When `--strictNullChecks` is off, `null` and `undefined` are considered assignable to *almost* any type.  This *almost* makes them [bottom types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom_type) like [the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type).  But, for whatever reason, they are *not* assignable to the `never` type.  This is a crucial difference (and the thing I might think of as a bug or limitation).  Only `never` is assignable to `never`:

  ```
  declare let never: never;
  declare let any: any;
  declare let v: never;
  v = undefined; // error!
  v = null; // error
  v = any; // error
  v = never; // okay
  ```
- When `--strictNullChecks` is off, `null` and `undefined` are absorbed into [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) (like `never`):

  ```
  type Foo = string | undefined;
  // type Foo = string
  ```
- When you try to assign a value to `obj[key]` for a `key` of a union type, TypeScript requires that the value be assignable to the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of the value types for each key in the union, as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#30769](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769):

  ```
  interface Bar {
    x: number | string;
    y: string | boolean;
  }
  const bar: Bar = { x: 3, y: true };
  for (const key of ['x', 'y'] as const) {
    bar[key] = 1; // error! number is not assignable to string
    bar[key] = "okay"; // okay
  }
  ```

Putting this all together:

In this code:

```
for (const key of ['a', 'b'] as const) {
  data[key] = undefined;
}
```

Because `data` is of type `Partial<IData>`, with `--strictNullChecks` *on*, this intersection would be `(number | undefined) & (string | undefined)` which evaluates to just `undefined`.  So `undefined` is the only safe value you can assign to `data[key]` when `key` is only known to be `"a"` *or* `"b"`.  And the above assignment compiles with no error.

But with `--strictNullChecks` *off*, `(number | undefined) & (string | undefined)` collapses to `number & string` which is just `never`.  And `undefined` is, for whatever reason, not assignable to `never`.  And the above assignment gives you the error you're facing.

Blah.

---

So, how can you proceed?  Assuming you don't want to turn on `--strictNullChecks` (which, again, is almost universally recommended), and you don't want to file an [issue in GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues) about it (which would probably end up being marked as "Working as Intended" or "Design Limitation", but maybe possibly would be marked as "Bug" which would be low on anyone's priority list to fix), then you can work around it via [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions).  You can just say "`undefined` is assignable to `never` here" and the compiler will accept it:

```
for (const key of ['a', 'b'] as const) {
  data[key] = undefined as never; // okay
}
```

Is this type safe?  Well, it's not really any less type safe than any other handling of `undefined` when `--strictNullChecks` is off.  Type assertions inherently let you do unsafe things, so you *are* taking some responsibility for safety away from the compiler.  But there's not much better that you can do here, unfortunately.

<sub>(Well, you know, except for turning on `--strictNullChecks`.  And all of [the `--strict` suite of compiler features](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strict), while you're at it.  The `--strict` option is a "standard" level of type which is used in a lot of code bases; if you have a question about TS and `--strict` or one of its sub-features is not enabled, you will find fewer resources to help you.  And the `--strict` suite is composed of features which have, in real world code bases, solved more problems than they've caused.  Features which tend to make things worse for the average code base are kept out, like [`--noUncheckedIndexedAccess`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#checked-indexed-accesses---nouncheckedindexedaccess) and [`--exactOptionalPropertyTypes`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#exact-optional-property-types---exactoptionalpropertytypes)).</sub>

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strict=false&noImplicitAny=false&strictNullChecks=false&strictFunctionTypes=false&strictPropertyInitialization=false&strictBindCallApply=false&module=1&ts=4.6.4#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)

Comment: Thanks jcalz. An amazing answer.

Still won't turn on strict null checks, though. 

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want

```
interface IData {
  a: number;
  b: string;
}

const data: Partial<IData> = {};

for (const key of ['a', 'b']) {
  data[key] = null;
}

console.log(data);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strict=false&noImplicitAny=false&strictNullChecks=false&strictFunctionTypes=false&strictPropertyInitialization=false&strictBindCallApply=false&module=1&ts=4.6.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBE5jsg3gWAChlk4AuZEAVwFsAjaAbiJLooGcwpQBzZwgL5EiCAPYhOyACZZyyAApwoYYHAA2AHgyyAfMgC8eAfzESwpKFDgBPAwG0A5HAcAaZA7oOAukRiioyAAUppIA1hC2ojAWVtYAlHgs0rJ24dZeBpRUamr8QoQi4uyiahAAdGqiPIEy2HGMQA)

But as per Calz's comment, not quite clear what your use case is

Comment: The problem with this solution is that there is no longer type safety. I can do `for (const key of ['a', 'c'])` and it will not catch the error.

Of course, in the real code, this array won't be literal, but defined elsewhere. The point is that it's an array of known keys, not an array of strings.